# Connecting PowerBI to Microsoft Graph or Azure AD

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, powerbi, office365, powerquery

My customer needs to connect their users and groups within Office 365 & Azure AD to Power BI, so they can show a report of the amount of users with certain licenties, the amount of RDS users and what type mailbox the users are using.

The whole proces needs to go automatically, so when PowerBI is opened the data is already ready for them and up to date.

[image: Problem and Customer Wishes]

**My solution was the following:**

1. Source,*Office 365 & Azure AD*), send the data to an API(Microsoft Graph)
2. Microsoft Graph exposes a webendpoint which another application can get the data from, IF they provide the **correct OAuth2 bearer token**-.
3. Access the webendpoint with Power BI and get the data when Power BI get's opened.

**PROBLEM**
I don't know how to refresh an OAuth2 token in Power BI, can someone help me?

[image: Postman authentication token]

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned this is officially ‘[unsupported](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/connecting-to-graph)’ but there is a workaround involving creating an Azure AD app registration with a client secret and the required permissions, using Web.Contents to pick up an OAuth 2.0 access token, then feeding that to the OData.Feed using ‘Authorization: Bearer’

There’s a sample here which does the job, including cloud refresh:

https://minkus.medium.com/easily-connecting-between-power-query-power-bi-and-microsoft-graph-72333eb95a35

Answer (score 0):

Connecting to Microsoft Graph REST APIs from Power Query isn't recommended or supported.

Read more here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/connecting-to-graph

Comment: What would be a route that I could take to get the information from Azure AD to Power BI, automatically?

Comment: Lots of options.  Azure Data Factory pipeline that hits the API, formats the response as a CSV, and then stores the result in our Azure Data Lake. Or Powershell script, automated in an Azure automation runbook that spits out CSVs somewhere.